# how to download android open source project on windows 8.1 machine?

Tags: android, open-source

I'm trying to download using the link http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html, but i'm getting error like " 'Module' has no attribute like 'symlink' ". Can any one help me to download the source please.

Thanks in-advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a 64 Bit Linux or Mac System for downloading and building the android source code. It is not working on Windows.

From the [documentation](http://source.android.com/source/building.html):

> Before you download and build the Android source, ensure your system meets the following requirements:
>
> A Linux or Mac system. It is also possible to build Android in a virtual machine on unsupported systems such as Windows. If you are running Linux in a virtual machine, you need at least 16GB of RAM/swap and 50GB or more of disk space in order to build the Android tree. See disk size requirements below.

Comment: But i've only 4GB of RAM in my system, is there any way to install linux with 4GB of RAM.

Comment: RAM is not a real issue. If you have less RAM the compile time will be longer. But I recommend you that if you only have 4 GB RAM you should not run the Linux in a virutal machine.

Comment: So, any other way to download source?

Comment: I am unsure what you want but you can clone the [repository](https://android.googlesource.com/).